# Amazon Seller API: IAM user permission question

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to use a IAM account and interact with Amazon Seller API to manage some reports, what policies or permissions should I get? I'm so confused here.

```
sp_api.auth.exceptions.AuthorizationError: ('unauthorized_client', 'Not authorized for requested operation', 400)
```

Comment: What is "aws sp api"? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: amazon seller partner api which is the REST API thats going to replace the old one

Comment: Might help? [How to access the Amazon Selling Partner API | Jesse Evers](https://jesseevers.com/selling-partner-api-access/)